Podman and Podman-Desktop Out of Sync for Images
Augh!!!
Somehow there is now a disjoint in viewing images between my Podman CLI and my Podman-Desktop. I create most of my images in Podman CLI.
I am running Podman-Desktop for Windows V5.1.1 and Podman CLI V5.1.1.
They share the same virtual machine. It's just one cannot see the others images.
Any help appreciated.
Lou
